How to load a Pre Trained VGG16 model using TensorFlow and generate a confusion matrix
I have trained a VGG16 model (from tensorflow.keras.applications) on 15 categories of images on 100 epochs. After training, I saved the model as a file named 'best_model.h5', but unfortunately, I forgot to include code in my script to generate a confusion matrix. Now, to get a confusion matrix, is it possible to somehow utilise the saved model file that I have (best_model.h5), without going over the hassle of training the model from scratch again?
This is the code I used to train my model
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from tensorflow.keras.applications import VGG16
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint


print("Set up directories for training and validation data...")
train_dir = '/scratch/user/nabarunkar/Disaster Dataset/train'
validation_dir = '/scratch/user/nabarunkar/Disaster Dataset/validation'

print("Image preprocessing for data augmentation...")
train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

print("Load images from directories...")

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),  # VGG16 expects 224x224 input
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Ensure this is set to 'categorical'
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Ensure this is set to 'categorical'
)


print("Build the VGG16 model...")
base_model = VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False, input_shape=(224, 224, 3))

print("Freeze the base model...")
base_model.trainable = False

print("Add custom classification layers on top...")
model = Sequential([
    base_model,
    Flatten(),
    Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    Dropout(0.5),
    Dense(15, activation='softmax') # 15 categories
])

print("Compile the model...")
model.compile(optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

print("Callbacks...")
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    'best_model2.h5',  # Path to save the best model
    monitor='val_loss',  # Metric to monitor
    save_best_only=True,  # Only save the model if the monitored metric improves
    mode='min',  # Save when the metric is minimized (for loss)
    verbose=1  # Print messages when saving the model
)

print("Train the model...")
history = model.fit(
    train_generator,
    epochs=100,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    callbacks=[checkpoint]
)

print("Evaluate the model on the validation set...")
val_loss, val_accuracy = model.evaluate(validation_generator)
print(f'Validation accuracy: {val_accuracy:.2f}')

I tried running this snippet to load the saved model and generate a confusion matrix:
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re

def extract_numbers(class_name):
    """Extract the numerical part from class names like 'cat01building'"""
    numbers = re.findall(r'\d+', class_name)
    return numbers[0] if numbers else class_name

def generate_confusion_matrix(model_path, validation_generator, class_names):
    # Load the saved model
    model = load_model('./best_model2.h5')
    
    # Get predictions
    # Reset the generator to ensure we start from the beginning
    validation_generator.reset()
    
    # Get predictions for the validation set
    predictions = model.predict(validation_generator)
    predicted_classes = np.argmax(predictions, axis=1)
    
    # Get true labels
    true_classes = validation_generator.classes
    
    # Generate confusion matrix
    cm = confusion_matrix(true_classes, predicted_classes)
    
    # Simplify class names to just numbers
    simplified_labels = [extract_numbers(name) for name in class_names]
    
    # Plot confusion matrix
    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 10))
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues',
                xticklabels=simplified_labels,
                yticklabels=simplified_labels)
    plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
    plt.ylabel('True Label')
    plt.xlabel('Predicted Label')
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)
    plt.yticks(rotation=45)
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.show()
    
    # Print classification report
    print("\nClassification Report:")
    print(classification_report(true_classes, predicted_classes, 
                              target_names=class_names))  




train_dir = '/content/dataset/train'
validation_dir = '/content/dataset/validation'

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255,
    rotation_range=20,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.2,
    zoom_range=0.2,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode='nearest'
)

validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Load images from directories

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    train_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),  # VGG16 expects 224x224 input
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Ensure this is set to 'categorical'
)

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    validation_dir,
    target_size=(224, 224),
    batch_size=32,
    class_mode='categorical'  # Ensure this is set to 'categorical'
)

class names = ['cat07', 'cat08', 'cat09', 'cat10', 'cat11', 'cat12', 'cat13', 'cat14', 'cat15', 'cat16', 'cat17', 'cat18', 'cat19', 'cat20', 'cat21', 'cat22', 'cat23']


# Generate confusion matrix
generate_confusion_matrix('best_model2.h5', validation_generator, class_names)```

but no matter what I try, I keep getting the same error as below:

> AttributeError: Exception encountered when calling Flatten.call().

'list' object has no attribute 'shape'

Arguments received by Flatten.call():
  • args=(['<KerasTensor shape=(None, 7, 7, 512), dtype=float32, sparse=False, name=keras_tensor_450>'],)
  • kwargs=<class 'inspect._empty'>


Looking at your code, I can see that you created new class called names instead of new variable class_names. Please re-check for typos.
